# Should we create a separate repository for each Activity or single repository for entire app

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-mvvm

I am following `MVVM` architecture for my app. In Activity I need to `getNews()` from a URL, if news is not already cached.

Activity will ask `ViewModel` to give the `News Json` and `ViewModel` will look into the repository, and decide to send data from local or remote repository.

Now the confusion stems from the following point: Should I create a separate Repository class for each Activity, or a general Repository class for the entire project with which each activity communicates. The repository class would be huge in the second approach.

I am unable to find out any official guideline on this topic, and I would like to know the best practice on this regard.

Answer (score 19):

Creating a single **repository** for the whole app is definitely not a good idea, since that will become very large and completely unmanagable very fast.

I would suggest that you create separate **repositories** for every **viewmodel** and additionally **services** for data that is used by multiple **viewmodels**.

In your example that would mean that you have a *NewsSource* **service** that takes care of retrieving and caching the news JSON and have all your **repositories** that need that data retrieve it from there.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty late for this, but it might be helpful for anyone else coming here!

The best practice recommended by Google (as of 2023 December) when using Repository Pattern is `to have a repository for each type of data source your app uses.`

You can further read here: [Add Repository and Manual DI](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-add-repository#1)

It further states that :

**What is a repository?**

In general a repository class:

- Exposes data to the rest of the app.
- Centralizes changes to data.
- Resolves conflicts between multiple data sources.
- Abstract sources of data from the rest of the app
- Contains business logic